# Express JS returns null for a query result and values are shown when queried with pgAdmin

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, pg-promise

I have the following code for querying a list of country names:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log("/");
  const query =
    `SELECT DISTINCT name
         FROM countries`;

  db.map(query, [], a => a.json)
    .then(data => {
      res.send({
        data: data,
        status: 200
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).send('Error occured');
    });
});
```

In response, I get the response as follows:

```
{
  "data": [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    ........
  ],
  "status": 200
}
```

But when I run the same query using pgAdmin, I get the country names instead of 'null'. Can someone help me figure out the issue? I'm a beginner and has no idea on what's going wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you execute `SELECT DISTINCT name FROM countries WHERE name is NOT NULL` ?

Comment: When querying in pgAdmin I get 211 names and the above code gives 211 null values. Same result with the above query @DavidR

Comment: which npm module are you using?

Comment: @RahulSharma pg-promise. Other queries are returning correct results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is selecting the field `name`, but you are mapping the results using a property called `json`. You should do the following:

```
db.map(query, [], a => a.name)
```